# Accuracy "overfits" but loss doesn't?

Tags: cross-validation, loss-functions, overfitting, accuracy

I'm perplexed as to why my loss doesn't go up when the accuracy goes down (after about 40 epochs). Isn't it possible to tell overfitting from the loss curve alone? (I'm of course referring the validation learning curve.)

Could someone please explain?

PS: I'm using "binary crossentropy" as the loss function in this particular case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the validation alone is never enough to draw accurate conclusions.

To be certain that your model is overfitting, you have to look at both training and validation. In total you can have 4 scenarios I guess, two of them are the most important ones:

- Underfitting: training and validation loss are increasing, probably unstable after each epoch as well
- Overfitting: training loss is decreasing while validation loss is increasing

Comment: I'm looking at both the training and validation curves (cf. the graphs). This still doesn't explain why accuracy reaches an inflection point while the loss doesn't.

Comment: I was mainly answering this question: _Isn't it possible to tell overfitting from the loss curve alone?_.